# Can this be improved?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Ok, I hope I can explain this in a good way.
I am creating an app (with react native) on where messages can be viewed. On the home screen you can see a badge with the unread/new messages. Somehow this is not working the first time the app loads, but when I navigate to another screen and back to home, it shows the badge (after a short delay, you will see this in the code).

Although it seems to work, I think there is room for improvement, so I hope one of you can take a look at the code and see where the improvements can be made.

This is the code I have so far:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.announce = firebase.firestore().collection('announcements');
        this.state = {
            newAnnouncements: 0,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let userId;
        let countHasRead;
        let countAnnounce;
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                userId = user.uid
            }
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.announce
                .get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    countAnnounce = snapshot.size;
                });
            this.announce
                .where('hasread.userId', '==', userId)
                .get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    countHasRead = snapshot.size;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                });
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({newAnnouncements: countAnnounce - countHasRead});
            }, 1000);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

And than use `this.state.newAnnouncements` in the badge.

Comment: I believe this is a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, will ask it there